# Javascript: How is an array with keys possible?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to understand how force works in d3 and while testing code in Chromes javascript console, I came across arrays like such:

```
[14, 7, index: 19, weight: 4, x: 823.4318332231393, y: 87.20455959056517, 
px: 823.4318332231393…]
```

Since I am not aware of Arrays being able to have anything other than numeric keys, I am a little confused.  How is this possible?  Array.isArray is true.

Comment: I'm confused too because this is a syntax error that throws an error in my console.

Comment: Are you sure those aren't objects in that array? Like: `var arr = [14, 7, {index : 19 }, {weight: 4} , {x: 823.4318332231393}, {y: 87.20455959056517}, 
{px: 823.4318332231393}]`

Comment: Arrays do *not* have keys, you are right. Something else is going on you aren't showing us.

Comment: @SterlingArcher I know, you are welcome to look at the sample source code https://gist.github.com/mbostock/1199811 . I am using Version 49.0.2594.0 canary and I did a console.log(nodes) at about line 34.

Comment: It's an array of arrays. The keys you are looking at are actually properties set on the array objects. Here's a [screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/oRleaBy.png).

Comment: @MinusFour thank you, I am trying to understand this further would you happen to have a link with more explanation.  If you do please put that as an answer.  So I can accept it.

Comment: There's little else I can say. Arrays are technically objects so it can have any valid object property.

Comment: @MinusFour okay I get it now, object properties.

Answer (score 4):

It looks to me like perhaps you've omitted some code, or perhaps have the incorrect snippet.

The closest acceptable format to what is in your question would be if they were anonymous objects within the array. Which would make sense, because d3 needs to know those specific properties (x, y, etc) to draw the elements.

My best assumption is that this is the actual array:

```
var arr = [14, 7, {index : 19 }, {weight: 4} , {x: 823.4318332231393}, {y: 87.20455959056517}, {px: 823.4318332231393}]
```

Which yields true for `Array.isArray(arr);`

Comment: I have added a link above with sample code of mbostock.  I wish it was as you suggested but arr[0] return 14 and arr[''weight'] returns 4.  Also I can not find in the d3 source code where some crazy Array.prototype mutation was made.

Comment: Then I think MinusFour is correct (I am behind a firewall and can't view his screen shot). It was either this, or his suggestion.